# How to convert AnyObject to PFObject/PFUser in swift?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am setting up a PFRelation for the user variable and I'd like to add the text in a textfield as a PFRelation. First I query to see if the input username exists, then I make the returned object a PFUser. Then i attempt to add the PFUser to PFRelation and that's where it crashes, because AnyObject cannot be downcasted to PFUser/PFObject. How would I go about doing that?

```
    var userQuery = PFUser.query()

userQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: newUsername.text)
userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

    if error == nil {

        for object in objects{
            if objects.count > 0 {
                var PFRelation = PFUser.currentUser().relationForKey("friends")
                var addRelation = object["username"] as PFUser
                PFRelation.addObject(addRelation)

                PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
                  (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) in

                    if error == nil {
                       println("newuser added")
                    }
                    else {
                       println(error.userInfo)
                    }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it couldn't be done because PFObject/PFUser is like an array. Thus I couldn't cast just an object into an array. I also used getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock() instead because it returns a PFObject instead of AnyObject, not sure if that made a difference. Below is my working code.

```
var userQuery = PFUser.query()

userQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: newUsername.text)
userQuery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{ (object, error) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
                println(object)
                var PFRelation = PFUser.currentUser().relationForKey("friends")
                var addRelation = object
                if addRelation != nil {
                PFRelation.addObject(addRelation)
                println("new relation added")
                }
                PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
                  (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) in

                    if error == nil {
                       println("newuser saved")
                    }
                    else {
                       println(error.userInfo)
                    }
                }
            }

    else {
            println(error)
         }
    }
```